# Maximal and prime ideals in polynomial rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

Consider the ideal $I=(ux,uy,vx,uv)$ in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Q}[u,v,x,y]$, where $u,v,x,y$ are indeterminates. Prove that every prime ideal $P$, containing $I$ contains the ideal $A=(x,y)$ or the ideal $B=(u,v)$. It is also to be proved that the following 3 statements are false: (a) Every prime ideal containing I contains the ideal $(x,y)$. 
(b) Every maximal ideal containing $I$ contains the ideal $(u,v)$. 
(c) Every maximal ideal containing I contains the ideal $(u,v,x,y)$. 
Towards solving this problem, I have that $\mathbb{Q}[x,y,u,v]\setminus P$ is an integral domain since $P$ is prime. I am not able to link this fact with $P$ containing $A$ or $B$. Also I just can’t get counter examples to prove that statements (a), (b) and (c) are false. I will be thankful for help for solving this problem.

Comment: Counterexample $\ P = (u,x).\ $ Perhaps you meant $\,I = (u,v)(x,y) = (ux,uy,vx,\color{#c00}{vy})?\ \ \ $

Comment: I humbly submit that the problem is correct. No typos. It’s uv not vy.

Comment: It can't be correct since then - as I said - the prime $\,P = (u,x)\,$ is a counterexample: it contains $I$ but does not contain $\,(x,y)\,$ or $\,(u,v)\ \ \ $

Comment: I see the point. You are absolutely correct. Will it be ok if I edit the problem with vy instead of uv as suggested by you?